# Passing multiple data through a postasync method in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Im trying to pass multiple data using a http postasync client method. Currently I am using a postasync on the client side and on the server side I have a post method that takes two parameters. My question is how do I successfully retrieve this information in the server side using c#. I want to be able to retrive the login information, and also the islogin boolean. How do I retrieve it in the server side. 
Here is the code of the server:

```
  // POST: api/Register
  [ResponseType(typeof(Login))]
  public IHttpActionResult PostLogin(Login login, bool isLogin) {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetLogin", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login.Email;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = login.Password;
            SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter("returnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var result = returnValue.Value;
            if (isLogin == true)
            {
                //int result = db.GetLogin(login.Email, login.Password);


                switch (result)
                {
                    case (int)DBResponses.Success:
                        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = 0 }, (int)DBResponses.Success);
                        return Ok((int)DBResponses.Success);

                    case (int)DBResponses.BadEmail:
                        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = 2 }, (int)DBResponses.BadEmail);
                        return Ok((int)DBResponses.BadEmail);
                    case (int)DBResponses.BadPassword:
                        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = 3 }, (int)DBResponses.BadPassword);
                        return Ok((int)DBResponses.BadPassword);
                    case (int)DBResponses.EmailNotVerified:
                        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = 4 }, (int)DBResponses.EmailNotVerified);
                        return Ok((int)DBResponses.EmailNotVerified);
                    case (int)DBResponses.EmailNotFound:
                        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = 5 }, (int)DBResponses.EmailNotFound);
                        return Ok((int)DBResponses.EmailNotFound);
                    default:
                        //NOTE: shouldn't reach this point
                        return Ok((int)DBResponses.GeneralFailure);
                        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = 6 }, (int)DBResponses.GeneralFailure);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (result)
                {
                    case (int)DBResponses.LoginEntryCreated:
                        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = 1 }, (int)DBResponses.LoginEntryCreated);
                        return Ok((int)DBResponses.LoginEntryCreated);
                    default:
                        return Ok((int)DBResponses.GeneralFailure);
                }


            }
        }
```

Here is the code for the client side:

```
   internal async Task<string> GetLoginAsync(Login login,bool isLogin) {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
        string json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(isLogin);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
        content.Headers.Add("isLogin", isLogin.ToString());
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage result = await c.PostAsync(development, content);
        string responseMessage = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (responseMessage == "0")
        {
            return "Success";
        }
        else if (responseMessage == "2")
        {
            return "BadEmail";
        }
        else if (responseMessage == "3")
        {
            return "BadPassword";
        }
        else if (responseMessage == "4")
        {
            return "EmailNotVerified";
        }
        else if(responseMessage =="5")
        {
            return "EmailNotFound";
        }
        //Should never reach this point
        else {
            return "GeneralFailure";
        }

    }
```

Comment: You really should create a Type that has `Login` and `bool` properties and send that as a single object to the controller.

Comment: Yeah that I was thinking but that would require changing alot of code in database and the project

Comment: I found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Call the API method through query strings, in that way all you need to do is read the query strings on the server side.
2. Serialize your object with JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjectHere), and on the other side you use DeserializeObject. Don't forget to add [serializable] to your entity definition (the class). You can also use HttpClient in doing the request itself

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand your question right, here is the solution
To send data from your Client side (JS) 
create an object

```
var logObj = new Object();
logObj.username = "";
logObj.password = "";
..
logObj.etc = "";
```

to return the information you could create a class like the following

```
class Loginfo
{
        public bool Islogin { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and return an object 
Wish this would help